# Indefinite Integration - with trignometric substitution

Tags: calculus, integration, algebra-precalculus, trigonometry, indefinite-integrals

$$\int \sqrt{\frac{\sqrt{x}-1}{ \sqrt{x}+1}} \,\,dx$$

The tip I got was to use $x= \sec^2(a)$. I don't no how to continue. I think there is trignometric simplification.

Comment: What did you get after making the suggested substitiion?

Comment: The expression with sec(a) instead of $\sqrt(x)$ there is a triginmetric identity or formula that i am forgetting to simplify.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

\begin{align*}
  x &= \sec^2 t \\
  dx &= 2\sec^2 t \tan t \, dt \\
  \sqrt{\frac{\sqrt{x}-1}{\sqrt{x}+1}} &=
  \sqrt{\frac{(\sqrt{x}-1)(\sqrt{x}-1)}{(\sqrt{x}+1)(\sqrt{x}-1)}} \\
  &= \frac{\sqrt{x}-1}{\sqrt{x-1}} \\
  &= \frac{\sec t-1}{\tan t} \\
  I &= \int \sqrt{\frac{\sqrt{x}-1}{\sqrt{x}+1}} \, dx \\
  &= \int 2\sec^2 t(\sec t-1) \, dt \\
  &= 2\int \sec^3 t\, dt-2\int \sec^2 t\, dt \\
  &= 2\int \sec^3 t\, dt-2\tan t \\
  \int \sec^3 t\, dt &= \int \sec t\, d(\tan t) \\
  &= \sec t \tan t-\int \tan t\, d(\sec t) \\
  &= \sec t \tan t-\int \tan^2 t \sec t\, dt \\
  &= \sec t \tan t-\int (\sec^2 t-1) \sec t\, dt \\
  &= \sec t \tan t-\int \sec^3 t\, dt+\int \sec t\, dt \\
  2\int \sec^3 t\, dt &= \sec t \tan t+\int \sec t\, dt \\
  \int \sec t\, dt &= \int \frac{\sec t \tan t+\sec^2 t}{\sec t+\tan t}\, dt \\
  &= \int \frac{d(\sec t+\tan t)}{\sec t+\tan t} \\
  &= \ln |\sec t+\tan t|+C \\
  I &= (\sec t-2)\tan t+\ln |\sec t+\tan t|+C \\
  &= (\sqrt{x}-2)\sqrt{x-1}+\ln (\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{x-1})+C
\end{align*}

Answer (score 1):

$$x = cos^2(t)$$

$$dx = -2sin(t)cos(t) dt$$

$$ I = \int \sqrt\frac{cost - 1}{cost + 1}(-2sin(t) cos(t) dt)$$

$$cos(t) = 1 - 2sin^2(t/2)$$

$$cos(t) = 2cos^2(t/2) - 1$$

$$ I = \int \sqrt\frac{cost - 1}{cost + 1}(-2sin(t) cos(t) dt)$$

$$ I = \int \sqrt\frac{-2sin^2(t/2)}{2cos^2(t/2)}(-2sin(t) cos(t) dt)$$

$$ I = \int \sqrt{-tan^2(t/2)}(-2sin(t) cos(t) dt)$$

$$ I = \sqrt{-1} \int tan(t/2)(-2sin(t) cos(t) dt)$$

Now it is very easy to integrate ....

Answer (score 0):

HINT: set $$t=\sqrt{\frac{\sqrt{x}-1}{\sqrt{x}+1}}$$ then we have $$x=\left(\frac{t^2+1}{t^2-1}\right)^2$$ and $$dx=-\frac{8(t^2+1)t}{(t-1)^3(t+1)^3}dt$$

Comment: I am supposed to used the trigonometric substitution in the problem. I already saw your method on "online integral calculator . com"

Answer (score 0):

**hint**

put $x=\cos^2(2t) $ and use

$$1-\cos(2t)=2\sin^2(t) $$

$$1+\cos(2t)=2\cos^2(t) .$$

Answer (score 0):

$$\int \sqrt{\frac{\sqrt{x}-1}{ \sqrt{x}+1}} \,dx=\int \frac{\sqrt{x}-1}{\sqrt{ x-1}}\,dx.$$

The term $-1$ at the numerator integrates immediately.

Then with $x=\cosh^2t$,

$$\int \frac{\sqrt{x}}{\sqrt{ x-1}}\,dx=2\int \frac{\cosh t}{\sinh t}\cosh t\sinh t\,dt=\int(\cosh 2t+1)\,dt.$$